# How much gas does a car use per-mile?

Tags: gasoline, mileage

On average, most people have a 40-60 gallon fuel tank and with that full can travel 200 - 300 miles. My question is, how much gas do your vehicle use per mile? What are some of the factors that dictate this and can they be altered?

Comment: You've heard of MPG right?  Miles per gallon is a constant topic on cars.  Also, an "average" car has a 13-14 gallon tank, not 40.

Answer (score 2):

The way to calculate the gallons per mile is as follows:

- Fill your tank to full and note the mileage
- Drive till the tank is down to about 1/3

  - Keep the driving to the kind you would normally do, or you will effect the results.
- Go back and fill the car up to full again, and note the mileage and how many gallons were put into the tank.
- To make your final calculation take the number of gallons you put into the tank and divide by the number of miles you drive since the first fill up. This your gallons per mile number.

Things that can effect this number are:

- The overall health of your engine. An engine in bad need of a tune up will get worse results.
- The kind of driving you do. Accelerating and coasting use radically different amounts of gasoline, so avoiding the acceleration gets you better mileage. Driving around town will be worse than driving on the highway.

Also, I don't know of any street car that had a 60 gallon tank short of an SUV like the old Ford Excursion. I'm not even sure if something that huge had a fuel tank that big. Using the mid-range of your numbers, 250 miles and 50 gallons, that gives an average of 5 miles to the gallon. Unless you are driving an M1 Abrams tank, your mileage is way better than this. Even my old monster SUV got 3 times better than that. Sadly, your base assumptions are really way off the mark, I would try for more real world numbers in researching this.

This is not really a topic for this forum, but I hope this gets you the info you need before we close it. We do appreciate your coming to the site and asking an honest question, but it's not really about mechanics for cars or motorcycles, so the likelihood is it will get closed.

Comment: Yeah I tried to cancel it as I did more research and found what I needed.

Comment: No problem at all! Glad it was useful info.